# LT spice directives don't 'stick' or save after editing and closing dialog boxes

Tags: ltspice

LT spice has been behaving weirdly for a few months now, This is the issue:

1. Click on a spice directive and open a dialog box
2. Change any text in the spice directive dialog box
3. Click 'OK'

after that the changes are not saved. I am wondering if this is an issue that anyone has run into or if it's just me (running win7). Has anyone encountered this bug in LT spice and was able to fix it?

[image]

Comment: I dont know the exact reason for this bug , I too have. For time being just press cancel and then the box will not disappear ! just type it there and it will be changed. This is just a hack and not a solution, even I got confused a lot of time. PS: I am also waiting for a proper solution

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if the win10 API has deviated from the win7 API so significantly, that current LTSpice isn't working properly on win7?  I've been using LTSpice on win10 for years now, on multiple computers and never had this sort of issue.

Comment: Are you also on win7 like OP?

Comment: I use windows 10 and I have this issue for some editors @Aaron

Comment: Nope, I use Win10 @Aaron

Comment: Well there goes that theory.

Comment: By the way , does this issue exist when try to change 'Edit simulation cmd' ? For me it happens for .step editor and some other boxes but not all

Comment: I'm having the same issue from time to time as well on my win10 pc. I don't recall seeing the issue at my work computer. Any recent LTspice update that screwed something up?

Comment: For me it's also on other dialog boxes, nothing sticks

Comment: @VoltageSpike The change I've noticed (because I'd developed a prior habit regarding earlier behavior) is that I ***must*** press the OK button now to get the change to stick. I used to be able to just hit ENTER and that was it. No longer. The problem is that hitting ENTER still closes the dialog as if it accepted it. And when the dialog is showing, the OK button is highlighted as the default button on the dialog as per the usual Windows rules for that. I'm on Win10 myself. I haven't bothered to try other Windows version nor do I use Linux and Wine. Write Mike about it, I'd say.

Comment: @VoltageSpike I just tried your example above. Worked fine for me if I press the OK button. And, oddly, worked okay when I hit ENTER, too. (Which I already know doesn't work sometimes.) Well, I'll see about collecting behavior data, now. I wonder if the fist time a dialog is popped there is a problem with the default button situation, but where a later use of the same dialog might work. Or visa versa? I don't know.

Comment: @jonk Thats what it is, I am on autopilot so much I thought I was clicking it when in reality I was pushing enter. That works now.

Comment: @jonk Alas Mike is no longer there, so the answers might not be the needed ones. Also, I use Wine/Linux and this problem doesn't happen. But I tend to use `Ctrl-RClick` to edit, to bring up the previous (LTspice IV) dialogs, so this is not a behaviour I've encountered.

Comment: I'll ping them and see if this is a bug that can be fixed.

Answer (score 3):

So the problem is I thought I was clicking ok when in reality I was pushing  the enter key. I'd imagine that if you push the enter key it's tied to the cancel button by default (if you actually tab down to the ok button and then hit enter it works, but the functionality of just hitting the enter button while in a dialog no longer works.